# Systemd service not recognizing python library

Tags: python, linux, systemd

I'm trying to run a python discord bot when my Raspberry Pi starts up. To do this, I've used a systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Testing

[Service]
Type=idle
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/discord/bug.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have done several test using simpler python programs before, and it all works fine. When trying to run the discord bot, it throws an error at the import statement. For testing I run:

```
sudo systemctl start bugstart
sudo systemctl status bugstart
```

The output of the status is the following:

```
bugstart.service - Testing
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bugstart.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-08-12 02:08:47 UTC; 1s ago
  Process: 1039 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/discord/bug.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1039 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 12 02:08:46 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Testing.
Aug 12 02:08:47 raspberrypi python3[1039]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Aug 12 02:08:47 raspberrypi python3[1039]:   File "/home/pi/discord/bug.py", line 1, in <module>
Aug 12 02:08:47 raspberrypi python3[1039]:     import discord
Aug 12 02:08:47 raspberrypi python3[1039]: ImportError: No module named 'discord'
Aug 12 02:08:47 raspberrypi systemd[1]: bugstart.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 12 02:08:47 raspberrypi systemd[1]: bugstart.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 12 02:08:47 raspberrypi systemd[1]: bugstart.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I found out that the commands are run as root, so I figured it might be that the library hand't been installed on root, but I tried importing discord in the command line shell and it worked fine.

Comment: `User=id` is there a user called id?

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk Sorry, that was a mistake, I've removed it from my code. I was typing User=pi and had a brain fart.

Comment: try `sudo -H pip install discord` or whatever the package name is

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk Running it right now, I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk It worked! Although now I have issues in my code I need to fix. If you put your response as an answer, and explain what it does I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try add

```
User=pi
Restart=always
```

to [Service].

like:

```
[Service]
Type=idle
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi
User=pi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/discord/bug.py
Restart=always
```